# import package javaEE

Tags: maven-2, java-ee-6, netbeans-7

I have a maven entreprise application project. How can I import a java Class included in a package (in EJB project) to a java Class that is in the Web project?

I simply try this:

```
import com.mycompany.persistence.UserEntity;
```

but I have this message :

> package does not exist

Is there a problem with dependencies?
 thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information provided in the question, it appears that the ejb project is not specified as a dependency in the web project.  Add this project as a dependency and it should work.

Comment: I tried to add the ejb project as dependency in the web project , in the Query field I put the name of the ejb package that I will use in the web project but in the search result : "no matching items". what should I do?